# https login request - selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, https, nosuchelementexception

I was trying to access a https login url to login to a page and do my actions, but unable to do the same.

These are my observations.

When I hit the actual url, internally its leading to another url having `JSESSION ID` appended to it and then loading the requested page [now actual url formed].

**Steps :**

- The actual url is like : `https:/abcd.xyz.com:7443/abcd/Web/Admin`
- when I hit the above url `driver.get("https:/abcd.xyz.com:7443/abcd/Web/Admin");` and when the test is running it appended Jsession id to another url, it looks like below,
        `https:/abcd.xyz.com:7443/abcd/loginAsGuest.jsp;jsessionid=z712Ty0Rn0BHLTH6Q2Q02cBj233L0JHwNhy7vxW9ntNZDbLJLxQT!-840704556`
- Then actual url is formed [`https://abcd.xyz.com:7443/abcd/Web/Admin`] with the page loaded.

Here my **problem** is, my script is not proceeding from there and getting `NoSuchElementFound` exception due to which am not able to login to the page.

Any help in resolving the above issue will be very much useful.

My Webdriver code looks like :

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://abcd.xyz.com:7443/abcd/Web/Admin");
WebElement uname = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
```

log shows something like this :

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"username"}

Any help in resolving the above issue will be very much useful.

Thanks,
-Anil  09566212889

Comment: Shouldn't your 'setAssume...' be set to true?

Comment: add some html of the Admin page.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be useful for you...

```
FirefoxDriver Driver=new FirefoxDriver();
Driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
Thread.sleep(1000);
Driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("xx");
Driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("xx");
Driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but I've used this method a few times. You need to form your get request with the login information you want to use like username:password@url.com. I can't remember where I saw to do this, but I'll try to dig it up.

In Python it would look like the following:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://username:password@192.168.1.1")
```